# How can I restore default settings and metrics in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, tcpip, gateway, routing-table

I have a Server 2019. With RAS installed and I have three NICs. I played around with the standard gateways to connect an IIS to the second NIC. Now I want to reset all routing and metric changes to get the default.

How to do that? (Without destroying the RAS settings)

Edit: I changed the metrics of the interfaces. But turning on the automatic values doesn't change anything. Or revert to the values, that I read in the docs.

Comment: We don't know what you have changed while playing around. If System restore is enabled, you could rollback Windows to before this was done.

Comment: I changed the metrics of the interfaces. But turning on the automatic values doesn't change anything.

Comment: You have maybe changed more than that. I assume System Restore is disabled?

Comment: Maybe. But System Restore seams to be to invasive.

Comment: How is System Restore invasive? It can be a life-saver. As you have turned it off, you now need to delete all your NICs and recreate them with default values.